# C# Live Data Architecture Best Practice

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, architecture

We are working on a software which measures radio data and visualizes the measurement on one or more clients.
To do so, we use a publish subscribe pattern and wcf callbacks. The server measures and if it has a new measurement it calls the callback method of the subscribed callbacks including the measured data as parameters, so the clients can visualize them.
In a windows world this works well. however we want to support android and ios devices as clients in the future, too. This is with the current architecture not possible.

My question is, what would be a best practice for this scenario?
I was thinking about a RESTful json service which is called frequently from all the clients to "ask" for new data. Is this a good approach?
Is there a way to use a pub/sub kind of system, which can work with ios and android as well?

To sum things  up:
1 service, measuring the data.
1 or more clients, consuming the data.
currently: service measures new data and calls client-callbacks with measurement data as params. No Android and iOS support.
future: andoid, ios and even more is needed, therefore new architecture has to be implemented.
I hope i could make things clear :)

any ideas? :)

Comment: This question is too broad and will elicit opinion-based answers. Please rephrase your question or risk having the question put on-hold.

Comment: Check out SignalR for a real-time web solution http://signalr.net

Comment: Agree with Ryan, SignalR, or any websockets compatible solution, looks like a good fit here. Once you bring security in the mix (and I can't see why you wouldn't), the overhead of HTTPS handshaking for individual requests will become a headache.

Answer (score 4):

I think SignalR is the best fit for such scenarios. Following links would help you more:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/590660/Introduction-to-SignalR , 
http://signalr.net/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR

To have an idea how to use it...there is a great article "*Building an HTML 5 Game
with **SignalR**, KnockoutJS & ASP.NET MVC*" **with sample application** in DotNetCurry magazine (free download) Issue 5 (Mar-Apr 2013) available at
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/magazine/dnc-magazine-issue5.aspx

Hope this would help. Thanks.